# Mongoose - Lean with Deep population

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to populate couple of objects together, when i try to access the parent object and add attribute to it, all is fine, but when editing an attribute inside an object of the parent, changes aren't applied.

```
let order = await Order.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }).populate({
  path: 'style',
  match: { removed: false },
  populate: [{
    path: 'processes',
    match: { removed: false },
    populate: { path: 'machine_type' }
  },
  { path: 'sizes' }]
}).lean();
```

When I try `order.style.processes[i].anyAttribute= AnyValue;` the object remains unchanged.

Comment: what value you are getting in `order` ?

Comment: @AlokDeshwal order.style.processes[i] is an object inside another inside an array which isn't null, when i add any attribute to it then log that variable i can't find my attribute